# Optimizing an Anagram Solver

Tags: python, optimization, performance, python-2.x

I've built an anagram solver in Python 2.7. It goes through a text file with over 100,000 words and checks if any permutations of the input matches the line. It works great, except it is very slow. I've tried making the text file a list with each line as a list item, but the text file is too big to do that. [This](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt) is the text file that I am using (it's saved on my flash drive).

```
# import permutations module
from itertools import permutations as prm

num_of_cases = int(raw_input("Input number of words needed to be unscrambled: "))
# take input
counter = 1
while counter <= num_of_cases:
   scrambled_word = list(str(raw_input("Input scrambled word: ")))

# empty lists that will be appended to later
   prm_list = []
   possible_words = []

# takes each permutation of the input and puts in a list
   for i in prm(scrambled_word):
      prm_list.append("".join(i))

   def check(x, y):

   # open list of words
      dictionary = file('E:\MRP\Text_Files\dictionary.txt')

      # check each line in the dictionary against each item
      # in the list of permutations and add it to another empty list if it's a match
      for line in dictionary:
         for i in x:
            if i+'\n' == line:
               y.append(i)


   check(prm_list, possible_words)

# delete duplicates
   possible_words = list(set(possible_words))

# print out possible words
   if len(possible_words) == 0:
      print "No matches found"
   else:
      for i in possible_words:
         print "Possible Word for Scrambled Word #" + str(counter) + ": " + i

# add to the counter
   counter+=1
```

If you test it out you can see that is very slow, especially as the words get larger. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of this program?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first comment is misleading (it's the `itertools` module not the permutations module) and useless anyway. Remove it.

There's absolutely no reason to rename `permutations` to `prm`. Don't do it.

`num_of_cases` would be better called `num_cases`, simply because it's more conventional.

Your `take input` comment is misplaced. It should be at the place it refers to.

`counter` is too vague: *what* are you counting? I would call it `num_matched_anagrams`.

You don't need to convert `scrambled_word` to a list. `permutations` accepts any iterable. You don't need to call `str` on the output of `raw_input`; it already returns a string.

The prior improvements make the comment `take input` really obvious, so you can remove that.

The later comments are often misaligned. Have them in line with the text.

`prm_list` can be generated with just `list(permutations(scrambled_word))`. This removes two comments.

`prm_list` should just be called `word_orders` or similar; don't bother naming things by their type.

`check` is badly named; it should be called something like `find_anagrams`.

`check` should not use `file`, which is deprecated, but `open`. It should also use `with` to handle the file.

`check` should save the dictionary between runs. In fact, this shouldn't really be `check`'s job at all.

The words should have their newlines trimmed, not the other way around.

`check` should only return anagrams, not deal with appending.

`check` should have sensibly named parameters.

`check` should just call `permutations` itself.

You do

```
possible_words = list(set(possible_words))
```

but why bother having `possible_words` as a list at all?

Instead of `if len(possible_words) == 0`, do `if not possible_words`. I would also switch the `if` around.

`num_matched_anagrams+=1` should have spaces: `num_matched_anagrams += 1`. The comment is obvious, so remove it.

Now to deal with speed.

`words` should be a set (since it's a set of words) and you loop over the permutations first. This allows a check of:

```
def find_anagrams(scrambled_word, words):
    for word_order in permutations(scrambled_word):
        potential_word = ''.join(word_order)

        if potential_word in words:
            yield potential_word
```

which is *much* faster.

We can improve this further by doing all the work upfront by making a cannonical, sorted version. This generates a mapping:

```
sorted word → [list of words that sort to this word]
```

This can be generated like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_anagrams = defaultdict(set)

with open('dictionary.txt') as dictionary:
   for word in dictionary:
      word = word.rstrip()

      word_anagrams[sorted(word)].add(word)
```

This then makes `find_anagrams` just `word_anagrams[sorted(scrambled_word)]`. This has high initial overhead (0.5 seconds for me with 170k words) but makes subsequent lookups insanely fast.

This gives the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_anagrams = defaultdict(set)

with open('dictionary.txt') as dictionary:
   for word in dictionary:
      word = word.rstrip()

      word_anagrams[''.join(sorted(word))].add(word)

num_cases = int(raw_input("Input number of words needed to be unscrambled: "))

num_matched_anagrams = 1
while num_matched_anagrams <= num_cases:
   scrambled_word = raw_input("Input scrambled word: ")
   sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(scrambled_word))

   if word_anagrams[sorted_word]:
      for word in word_anagrams[sorted_word]:
         print "Possible Word for Scrambled Word #" + str(num_matched_anagrams) + ": " + word

   else:
      print "No matches found"

   num_matched_anagrams += 1
```

The loop can be replaced with `for num_matched_anagrams in range(1, num_cases+1)`.

The whole thing should be put into a `main` function.

The dictionary parsing could be extracted to another function.

The `print` should use formatting and I'd add brackets for Python 3 compatibility:

```
print("Possible Word for Scrambled Word #{}: {}".format(num_matched_anagrams, word))
```

To complete Python 3 compatibility, add this to the top:

```
try:
   input = raw_input
except NameError:
   pass
```

This gives:

```
from collections import defaultdict

try:
   input = raw_input
except NameError:
   pass

def parse_dictionary(filename):
   word_anagrams = defaultdict(set)

   with open(filename) as dictionary:
      for word in dictionary:
         word = word.rstrip()

         word_anagrams[''.join(sorted(word))].add(word)

   return word_anagrams

def main():
   word_anagrams = parse_dictionary("dictionary.txt")

   num_cases = int(input("Input number of words needed to be unscrambled: "))

   for num_matched_anagrams in range(1, num_cases+1):
      scrambled_word = input("Input scrambled word: ")
      sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(scrambled_word))

      if word_anagrams[sorted_word]:
         for word in word_anagrams[sorted_word]:
            print("Possible Word for Scrambled Word #{}: {}".format(num_matched_anagrams, word))

      else:
         print("No matches found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Note that this is the same technique as Prashant gave.

Comment: All this code works great, but I'm still confused on what `parse_dictionary` does.

Comment: @michaelpri It makes the `sorted word → [set of words that sort to this word]` dictionary. For example, it could have `{ader: {dare, dear, read}, ...}` so if you type in `drae` it will sort to `ader` which will then give you the associated set `{dare, dear, read}`.

Answer (score 10):

If I remember correctly, I answered a similar question yesterday
[Finding the given word from jumbled letters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74981/finding-the-given-word-from-jumbled-letters/74983#74983)

Basically, doing permutations is going to take too long: a double `for` loop results in a complexity of \$O(n²)\$.

As suggested in the link, use sorting and scan linear if the output is correct or use the second approach described by thepace, which runs in \$O(n)\$

Perhaps you could run through the word file and try each word with one of the above approaches. (I believe this will run faster)

Regarding to your python code, may I suggest to use a main() function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041238/why-use-def-main) and call it by using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

This is a common convention and splits your main code and your other functions in a clear way. It also prevents the code being run while it's included as a module.

goodluck!

Comment: I would say that there's a better approach than sorting. And it is counting letters. Simply then see if each word has the same amount of letters. I'm not sure about that, though.

Comment: That's the approach being described by thepace ;)

Answer (score 5):

A few things I'd suggest changing in your implementation:

- Double loop resulting in O(n^2) complexity (we need a different algo)
- Permutation is the main culprit .. we might be able to bypass it completely
- Loading from the file in every loop (it's the same file .. we can load it once and use it as reference)
- The raw input in a while loop (let's just ask the user to enter all strings in one go .. maybe a comma separated input?)

Here's my take on a (hopefully) improved version:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def load_dictionary():
    saved_dict = []
    dictionary = file('<PATH TO YOUR words.txt file>')
    for line in dictionary:
        saved_dict.append(line.strip())
    return saved_dict


def sort_string(input_str):
    return ''.join(sorted(input_str))


def fetch_input_strings():
    input_strs = raw_input("Input scrambled word, seperated by comma: ")
    return [i.strip() for i in input_strs.split(',')]


def main():
    input_strings = fetch_input_strings()

    known_strings = load_dictionary()
    known_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for known_string in known_strings:
        known_dict[sort_string(known_string)].append(known_string)

    for input_string in input_strings:
        sorted_string = sort_string(input_string)
        if sorted_string in known_dict:
            print "Possible Words for Scrambled Word %s = %s" % (input_string, known_dict[sorted_string])
        else:
            print "No matches found for word %s" % (input_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The following is a sample output:

```
$python anagram.py 
Input scrambled word, seperated by comma: abt,able, aardvark,raltmas
Possible Words for Scrambled Word abt = ['abt', 'bat', 'tab']
Possible Words for Scrambled Word able = ['able', 'bale']
Possible Words for Scrambled Word aardvark = ['aardvark']
No matches found for word raltmas
```